# alasql exported excel formula not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, excel-formula, alasql

On my html page, I am using below code to create and download excel file.
I am creating this dynamic file with lot many formullas.

```
let db = new alasql.Database('TEMPDB');
db.exec('create table tempexcel(A string,B string, c string)');
db.exec('insert into tempexcel("5","6","=A1+B1")');
db.exec('select * INTO XLSX("tempex.xlsx",{headers:false})  from tempexcel');
```

This code is working fine to generate excel. But when I open excel content for C1 cell is =A1+B1
If I will hit enter on it, it will evaluate the value. I want to evaluate this values for all the cells. can you please guide do I need to change something in excel or in alasql API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For:

```
db.exec('create table tempexcel(A string,B string, c string)');
```

Checking [the data types](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/Data-Types) for alasql there's nothing for e.g. `xlfunction` so `string` is your best bet for column `c`.

So, the problem must be within alasql itself which leverages a library called xlsx to do Excel workbook creation. [See here in the prepareSheet function](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/blob/master/src/833xlsx.js):

```
for (var j = 0; j < dataLength; j++) {
    columns.forEach(function(col, idx) {
        var cell = {v: data[j][col.columnid]};
        if (typeof data[j][col.columnid] == 'number') {
            cell.t = 'n';
        } else if (typeof data[j][col.columnid] == 'string') {
            cell.t = 's';
        } else if (typeof data[j][col.columnid] == 'boolean') {
            cell.t = 'b';
        } else if (typeof data[j][col.columnid] == 'object') {
            if (data[j][col.columnid] instanceof Date) {
                cell.t = 'd';
            }
        }
        cells[alasql.utils.xlsnc(col0 + idx) + '' + i] = cell;
    });
    i++;
}
```

There's nothing to check if the cell should be flagged as a formula and considers just numbers, strings, booleans and dates (reasonably consistent with the data types documentation).

In the XLSX library, [it's straightforward to flag a cell as a formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520596/how-to-set-formula-for-cell-data-for-export-to-xlsx-sheetjs-js-xlsx-https). So we can apply that to the alasql code e.g.

```
for (var j = 0; j < dataLength; j++) {
    columns.forEach(function (col, idx) {
        var isFormula = false; 
        var d = data[j][col.columnid];
        var cell;
        if (typeof d == 'string') {
            isFormula = d.substr(0, 1) == '=';
        }
        if (!isFormula) {
            cell = {v: data[j][col.columnid]};
            if (typeof data[j][col.columnid] == 'number') {
                cell.t = 'n';
            } else if (typeof data[j][col.columnid] == 'string') {
                cell.t = 's';
            } else if (typeof data[j][col.columnid] == 'boolean') {
                cell.t = 'b';
            } else if (typeof data[j][col.columnid] == 'object') {
                if (data[j][col.columnid] instanceof Date) {
                    cell.t = 'd';
                }
            }   
        } else {
            cell = {f: d.substr(1, d.length - 1)};
        }           
        cells[alasql.utils.xlsnc(col0 + idx) + '' + i] = cell;
    });
    i++;
}
```

If the value is a string, and begins with `=` then tell XLSX to output in a way that Excel knows it's a formula (and chop off the `=`). Otherwise, just do what alasql is already doing. That's an untested, poorly implemented hack by the way - but IMHO the answer to your question.

If you hack that into the `alasql.fs.js` file in node_modules then your original code will just work the way you expect.

I took the liberty of [raising an issue](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/issues/1273) in the alasql project about this.

Comment: Hi @robin  I tried this by updating in alasql.js, after refreshing cache and after downloading excel formula shows as it as, I need to hit enter to get the result

Comment: @JigarParekh - I had to make the change in `alasql.fs.js`. I tried  `alasql.js` first and that didn't work for me. Didn't touch the cache.